# What is the difference between the logic of these 2 codes?

Tags: logic, logical-operators, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have 2 lines of code. Their logic looks the same to me but I am experiencing some bugs which seem to suggest I am wrong.

Code 1;

```
A and B and C
OR (AA and BB) and CC
OR (AAA and BBB) and CCC
or (AAAA and BBBB) and CCCC
```

Code 2:

```
(A and B and C)
OR (AA and BB and CC)
OR (AAA and BBB and CCC)
or (AAAA and BBBB and CCCC)
```

Am I right that both codes are logically equivalent? I fail to see any difference.

Comment: I agree, both versions should be identical logically.

Comment: AND binds tighter than OR, and AND is associative and communative so yes, they should be equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

Both codes are logically equivalent. No difference.